# Google Sheets: assign a non-changing custom format to a range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, cells

In Google Sheets, I'd like to set the default format of a range of cells that are currently empty, such that whenever data is entered into any of those cells in the future, that data is always automatically formatted the way I desire, without my having to manually format it after entering it.

For example, I'd like range A2:B1000 to ***always*** (!!!) be formatted with `%Y-%b-%D %H:%M:%S` as soon as I enter data into any of those cells.

I can select the range of cells use the `Format` menu to set this format to that range, but then, as soon as I enter anything that looks like a date into any of those cells, it gets formatted using the default, not my specified format.

And even if enter data and format it the way I want, if I clear that data from any of those cells, I'd like the formatting to be "sticky" and always remain, so that if I add more data later, it will still automatically get formatted the way I want.

I have not been able to find a way to do this permanent, sticky formatting in Google Sheets. Is it even possible?

Comment: Ugh! I was hoping I didn't have to do that :) Oh well, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I understand. But Excel and Librecalc (to name but two) do offer sticky, per-cell formatting. But I understand that Google Sheets is a different piece of software, and I will accomodate.

Comment: Hmm ... I thought I could do it with Excel; I certainly could do it with Librecalc. But these are moot points, and I probably shouldn't have even brought up other spreadsheets. I'm using Google Sheets, and I need to make this work with _that_ software. Anyway, thanks a lot for all your feedback.